# Cannot get from local storage for my layout.tsx

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js14

i am build next14 with typescript, i can store my access token jwt and isLogin to my localstorage, but when i get the key from my layout.tsx component i can not get the value
my goal is when the isLogin == yes the router will redirect to my /dashboard route
my code is :

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function SetupLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const isLogin = localStorage.getItem("isLogin");
    if (isLogin !== "yes") {
      console.log(isLogin);
      redirect("/sign-in");
    } else {
      redirect("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

i already search for this in internet but no clue

Comment: my recommendation is use cookies. NextJs using server side render, the window object is not defined there

Comment: Show the value printed by the console.